# Macro excel to word

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on the macro which can copy and paste the data excel to word to create the offer letter. Example, we already have the offer letter template in which we will have to modify the few details to roll out offer letter. could you please help me to fix this or it would be big help if you can provide me the new code.

please find the below codes

```
Public Declare Function CountClipboardFormats Lib "user32" () As Long

Dim appWd As Word.Application
Dim wdFind As Object
Dim ClipT As String

Function IsClipboardEmpty() As Boolean
        IsClipboardEmpty = (CountClipboardFormats() = 0)
End Function


Sub CheckClipBrd()
    If IsClipboardEmpty() = True Then
        ClipEmpty.PutInClipboard
    End If
End Sub


Sub FormatPaste()
    wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
    wdFind.Forward = True
    wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    wdFind.Execute
    Call CheckClipBrd
    appWd.Selection.Paste
    CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Sub NoFormatPaste()
    wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
    wdFind.Forward = True
    wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    wdFind.Execute
    Call CheckClipBrd
    appWd.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Sub CopyDatatoWord() 
    Dim docWD As Word.Document
    Dim OL As Object  

    Set appWd = CreateObject("Word. Application")
    appWd.Visible = True
    Set docWD = appWd.Documents.Open("\\X:\Users\yuan\Financial Director - Offer Letter.docx")

    'Select Sheet where copying from in excel
    Set OL = Sheets("OL")
    Set wdFind = appWd.Selection.Find
    ClipT = "  "

    OL.Range("B4").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "<Date>"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B6").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty02"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B7").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty03"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B8").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty04"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B9").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty05"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B11").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty06"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B13").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty07"
    Call FormatPaste

    OL.Range("B15").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty08"
    Call NoFormatPaste

    OL.Range("B17").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty09"
    Call NoFormatPaste

    OL.Range("B18").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty10"
    Call NoFormatPaste

    OL.Range("B20").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty11"
    Call NoFormatPaste

    OL.Range("B22").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty12"
    Call NoFormatPaste

    OL.Range("B24").Copy
    wdFind.Text = "Qwerty13"
    Call NoFormatPaste
End If


    'docWD.SaveAs (Dir2 & ".docx")
    docWD.SaveAs ("\\annapurna\Shared\Practice Quarterly Reports\Q1_2011\Test.docx")

    'appWD.Quit

    Set appWd = Nothing
    Set docWD = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in where your actual issues are. Where do you get errors and which? What does your code actually do instead of what you expect it to do? • In your `Sub CopyDatatoWord` there is an `End If` but no `If`!

Comment: Surely it would be easier to do this with a [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3), and just change the data on the Input Sheet in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a simpler way to do this, but what I've done in the past is embed a WORD template into my excel workbook on another worksheet. The WORD doc has empty bookmarks for where I want to input info. So I basically just open the embedded doc, save a blank copy of it to the user's computer (business requirement to ensure we also use a blank template), then open that blank copy we just saved and fill it out. Then save it.

```
'opens embedded doc
Set o = .OLEObjects("Object 1")
      o.Verb xlVerbOpen

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc2 As Word.Document
Dim nIndex As Integer

Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument

'must have already named your FilePath
'saves blank copy of template to the user's computer. will override if one exists.
wdDoc.SaveAs2 FilePath & "temp-name" & ".docx"

'closes out of the original doc. then opens the one we saved to the computer
    wdDoc.Close
    WDApp.Quit

Set WDApp2 = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc2 = WDApp2.Documents.Open(FilePath & "temp=name" & ".docx")
Set objRange = wdDoc2.Bookmarks("Plan").Range

WDApp2.Visible = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'fills out the bookmarks in the doc with values from the worksheet        
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Pol").Result = Range("B2").Value & Range("E2").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Pol2").Result = Range("B2").Value & Range("E2").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Name").Result = Range("C3").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Name2").Result = Range("C3").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Owner").Result = Range("C8").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("DueDate").Result = Range("B5").Value
    wdDoc2.FormFields("Amt").Result = Format(Range("B6").Value, "Currency")

'shows the doc so the use could review, and then press OK to save (not required)
WDApp2.Visible = True

    MsgBox "Please Review Letter and Press OK to Continue"

    WDApp2.Visible = False

'saves as a docx and a PDF

    wdDoc2.SaveAs2 FilePath & "filename" & ".docx"

    wdDoc2.SaveAs2 FilePath & "filename" & ".pdf", 17

    wdDoc2.Close
    WDApp2.Quit

    MsgBox "Letter Created Successfully!"

    Set WDApp2 = Nothing
    Set wdDoc2 = Nothing
```

Maybe that could help you if all else fails.